# Google Streaming Speech Recognition on an Audio Stream Java - Example App

Tags: java, audio, google-cloud-speech

I need do following with my web app.

1.Stream audio from webpage & submit to google cloud speech API & get the result. For that  I want to know following?
   1.how can i get the audio stream from webpage (access microphone) & submit to 
     speech API by using web socket or javasdk.

There is a sample for streaming api in java sdk samples but it loading file 
 from local files. Not real time reading from microphone.

2.How can i do text-to-speech using google cloud API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pradeep